# Validating zip files using System.IO.Compression

Tags: c#, .net, zip

Is there any way to check if a file is a valid zip file using System.IO.Compression functionality?

Comment: Try to decompress it or at least read an entry from it?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

The solution: open the zip archive using the [ZipFile.OpenRead()](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.compression.zipfile.openread) method and list all entries; if no exception happens, then the archive is valid.
For instance:

```
    public static bool IsZipValid(string path)
    {
        try
        {
            using (var zipFile = ZipFile.OpenRead(path))
            {
                var entries = zipFile.Entries;
                return true;
            }
        }
        catch (InvalidDataException)
        {
            return false;
        }
    }
```

Comment: If there's a CRC error on one of the zip entries, this does not catch it.

Comment: @itsmatt that doesn't happen often. But if it's necessary for your task, reading all the files is probably the only option.

Answer (score 5):

Extract ZIP file using [`ExtractToDirectory`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh485723(v=vs.110).aspx) and write code for invalid ZIP file within [`InvalidDataException`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.invaliddataexception).

About "InvalidDataException" Exeption:-

The archive specified by sourceArchiveFileName is not a valid zip archive.

-or-

An archive entry was not found or was corrupt.

-or-

An archive entry was compressed by using a compression method that is not supported.

```
        try
        {
            string startPath = @"c:\example\start";
            string zipPath = @"c:\example\result.zip";
            string extractPath = @"c:\example\extract";

            ZipFile.CreateFromDirectory(startPath, zipPath);

            ZipFile.ExtractToDirectory(zipPath, extractPath);
        }
        catch (InvalidDataException ex)
        {
            //Handle invalid zip here
        }
```